# jquery selector query grouping ors and ands

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, custom-data-attribute

Okay, so I've got myself into a real awkward situation here and I'm trying to create a selector for a specific set of rules.

Each element has a series of data- attributes and I'm trying to match some, the query goes something like this

```
select all elements where data-1 contains (any of these)
and with data-1 starts with this
and with data-1 starts with that
and with data-2 is this
and with data-3 is this
and with data-3 is this.
```

So that's it in human speak, the problem I'm having is specific to the first part of the query where I need to effectively group a set of ors and then throw an and on the end

doing `[data-1*="this"],[data-1*="that"][data-1^="thing"]` results in

```
select all elements where data-1 contains "this" or
select all elements where data-1 contains "that" and data-1 starts with "thing".
```

can anyone help me figure this out? It would be ideal to have it as a single query rather than several.

What I'd like to see possible is `([data-1*="this"],[data-1*="that"])[data-1^="thing"]` effectively grouping the ors into a single part of the query, but alas that does not work.

Comment: what are you trying to express??

Comment: Maybe you could chain some `.filter()` calls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339011/a-combination-of-and-and-or-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: Try the following   $('yourparentElement[data-1:contains("--,--,--")]').further your acitons.if you can share your code i can figure out more easily.

Comment: I really don't understand what is your condition....

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `with data-1 starts with this
and with data-1 starts with that`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go against the attributes at all.  Updating an elements data (with e.g. `$('.myclass').data('foo', 'bar')` does not update the attributes.  The attributes set the initial values of the elements data but that is all.

In your case I would recommend using jQuerys filter function.  Something like

```
$('.some-class-common-to-all-candidates').filter(function(){
   var d = $(this).data('1');
   if( 'foo' == d ){
       return true;
   } else if( d > 10 ){
       return true;
   }
   // If we get this far then no match
   return false;
})
```

Untested and I made up the conditions but you should get the gist.

[jQuery filter documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: `filter()` is definitely what is needed. Worst case can use the data attribute itself in selector without value such as `$('[data-1]')`

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, especially the link to the documentation. I knew something like this existed I just couldn't for the life of me remember :).