# Mixing logical AND and OR in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have to filter a list of items, that contain two crucial data attributes:

```
<li class="song" data-title="freedom" data-id="7" data-tags="tag-18-eot,tag-2-eot" data-category="1">Freedom</li>
```

1. Category
2. Tags

Filtering by category should be by logical OR but filtering by tags should be by logical AND.

Filtering using one of these two is not a problem.

I applied, for example:

```
$(collection).filter('li[data-tags*="tag-50-eot"][data-tags*="tag-51-eot"]');
```

to filter by tags. Or:

```
$(collection).filter('[data-category="1"], [data-category="2"]);
```

to filter by category.

This works fine. However, i could not find a way to combine these two selectors into one single query that i can pass to the `filter()` function, and chaining two `filter()` calls does not lead to the desired result, because the first call might filter out items that the second call would leave behind.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339011/a-combination-of-and-and-or-in-jquery-selectors) with a similar topic, but the problem is a little different and the approach as well.

How can I filter those items correctly?

Comment: Have you tried simply chaining with the AND first?

Comment: _chaining two filter() calls does not lead to the desired result, because the first call might filter out items that the second call would leave behind._ What makes you think so?

Comment: Not certain what expected result is? Return all elements which have `data-tags` and `data-category` attributes set?

Comment: If I understood correct you need apply the first filter anyway, so I don't see a problem with chaining two filter() calls.

Comment: @MattWay – wow, sometimes the solution is extremely simple, and shockingly logical. Post an answer so i can accept?

Comment: @hindmost Because that's what happens if you chain the filter commands with the OR first. As Matt Way pointed out however, if done the other way around, it works. Which makes an awful lot of sense, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to get what you are looking for with chaining, as long as you use the `AND` condition first. For example:

```
var res = $('#collection li')
    .filter('li[data-tags*="tag-50-eot"][data-tags*="tag-51-eot"]')
    .filter('[data-category="1"], [data-category="2"]');
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/um9o9pkw/).

Answer (score -2):

the filter function can receive a function as input...

You may end up with a construct like:

```
var set = $(collection).filter(
function( index, element )
{
    return ($(element).attr(...) == "...");
}
);
```

Comment: I don't get the downvote... I think the purpose of the site is to point people in the right direction, not to do their work for them.